# Changing the style of an 1-cell inside a 2-cell diagram, in xy

Tags: xymatrix

Is it possible to modify the style of the arrows in a 2-cell in `xy`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
 \UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
&B \ar[d]^g\dllowertwocell^{fg}_{1}{\epsilon} \\
B \ar[r]_g  \ar[ur] & A
}

\end{document}
```

I would like the codomain of \epsilon to be drawn as an identity, since it is one. `\dllowertwocell@{=}^{fg}_{1}{\epsilon}` has, of course, no effect since it is impossible to tell xy which arrow must be modified. Also, even the command that says at which point to put the label (let's say `\ar[r]^(.25){f}`) doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Sure, I did it (whoops, it's rather big)

Comment: Well, I know how to solve the problem in tikz-cd. My question was whether xy offers this possibility too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP has solved your question using tikz-cd.